# regex match unknown number of letters at end of string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to check that a string ends with a bunch of letters. The letters can can be any length.

I'm having difficulty combining the end-of-string and 1-or-more symbols. What I have is:

`([a-z]+)`

This also finds a match in item 3 below when it shouldn't

1. 235235isk
2. 25 euro
3. 1dollar 23

Comment: You can just use anchor as in `[a-zA-Z]$`

Comment: It should be `([a-z]+)$`